# Unable to locate dynamic input element with Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a `textfield` in my application , it gets enabled when i click on it. I am able to do click using  *CSS* but i am unable to enter text when it got highlighted.

I tried using **xpath** to idenfify the dynamicly but webdriver is throwing an error

> "Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='x-form-field
>   x-form-text']"}![enter image description here][1]

showed the difference before n after clicking on the field in thescreen shot.

Please help in how to dynamically identify and enter the text in that field

Comment: have u solved it out?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
 String cssSelector = "[class='x-form-field x-form-text']"
//but verify found css selector in firepath, firebug addon in ffox to make sure selenium //locate web element for input properly.
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).sendKeys("blablabla");
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String cssSelector = ".x-form-field x-form-text"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).sendKeys("blablabla");
```

Let me know is the above scripting is working or not.